# How to insert a random view beneath any UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, user-interface

Sorry for the influx of UI and GUI questions but I was recently looking at an application called Ganna and in this pic below I was wondering how you would get that random `Ganna Around The Globe` banner beneath the `Recently Played` horizontal collection view and above the `Top Charts` horizontal collection view.

[image]

The way it's organized is that there is a main collection view with multiple horizontal collection views such as the `Recently Played` and `Top Charts` horizontal collection view.

I am thinking if the indexPath is 0 (which means you are at the `Recently Played` horizontal collection view) then you would insert that `Ganna Around the Globe` banner underneath that collection view. But this would be difficult since I would have to return different heights of the cell depending on whether that banner exists or not. And this banner appears 3 times beneath 3 different horizontal collection views.

Do you guys have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I think there are 2 collection views not 1.and there is a banner in between !!!

Comment: Hi! Can you please let me know how there are 2 collection views in the above picture?

Comment: You are saying that there is one collection view which has 2 horizontal collection views right. I am saying that there are two collection views and banner in between space. Got ?

Comment: Oh ok but how do you insert that banner between the two collection views? Do I have to implement a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if this is how that particular example is implemented. But the way I would approach this is fairly simple.

You would have a single TableView with dynamic cells that covers the entire screen from nav bar to tab bar. Make two custom cells, the first custom cell contains a collectionView. The second cell would be laid out in whatever manner you want for displaying that banner.

In your cellForRow method of the tableViewDelegate you set the delegate of the collectionView inside the cell to whatever it needs to be.

The only thing left after that is a tiny piece of logic in the heightForRow method. Something like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.row == kBannerCellIndex) {
        return showBanner ? kBannerHeight : 0
    }
    // the rest of any height logic
    return defaultCellHeight
}
```